# Test my own composer package does not work

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to make a composer package. However, I am still in the development phase, would or would but the earlier test out.

I have an empty `vendor` folder with the autoloader from composer:

```
/vendor
  /composer
autoload.php
```

So now I've tried my package "simulate" and creates my folder structure and composer.json:

```
/vendor
  /composer

  /me
    /package
      /src
      /tests
      composer.json

autoload.php
```

This is my composer.json:

```
{
   "name": "me/package",
   "description": "",
   "license": "",
   "authors": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "email": ""
    }
   ],
   "minimum-stability": "dev",
   "require": {
     "php": ">=5.4.0"
   },
  "autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
     "Me\\Package\\": "src/"
   }
 }
}
```

And here is my class:

```
namespace Me\Package;

class Test {
  // ...
}
```

If I want to call it:

```
if(file_exists('vendor/autoload.php')) require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$test = new \Me\Package\Test();
```

i become `Fatal error: Class 'Me\Package\Test' not found`.

Of course, I also inserted a composer.json in the root directory, but I can still bad at `require` my package state since it was not published, right? But how do I test it then and say to composer he should autoload my package?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use composer to include a package that is not listed on http://Packagist.org/ you would add a '[repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories)' stanza into the composer.json (project root file). This reads the project, and gets the composer.json from it, using the name for the main-'requires' section.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/example/private-repo.git"
    }
}
```

The 'url' part, can also in fact be any valid URL for a git, SVN or HG repository - even a file:// based reference.